# MemoryError in Python when saving list to dataframe

Tags: python, memory

I was trying to do the following, which is to save a python list that contains json strings into a dataframe in jupyternotebook

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(mon_list)
df[['gfmsStr','_id']]
```

But then I received this error:

```
MemoryError
```

Then if I run other blocks, they all start to show the memory error. I am wondering what caused this and if there is anyway I can increase the memory to avoid the error.

Thanks!

update:
what's in mon_list is like the following:

```
mon_list[1]

[{'id': 1, 'name': {'first': 'Coleen', 'last': 'Volk'}},
        {'name': {'given': 'Mose', 'family': 'Regner'}},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Faye Raker'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really have a list? Or do you have a JSON file? What format is the "mon_list" variable?

This is how you convert a list to a Dataframe

```py
# import pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
  
# list of strings 
lst = ['Geeks', 'For', 'Geeks', 'is',  
            'portal', 'for', 'Geeks'] 
  
# Calling DataFrame constructor on list 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-lists/

Comment: My bad. Mon_list is actually a list and each list item is a json string

Comment: You can easy convert the JSON strings to dictionaries in python. Then you can make a data frame from the dictionary. Python is better att handling dictionarys.  You can convert it to a dictionary via d = json.load(json_file)